# Soap answert string - convert into arrray

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I have an Soap answer into php like these :

> [...]1|Name of  some Company
>            2|Name of  some Company
>            3|Name of  some Company
>            4|Name of  some Company
>            5|Name of  some Company
>            6|Name of  some Company
>            7|Name of  some Company
>            8|Name of  some Company
>            9|Name of  some Company

I need to convert in into php array like these

```
Array (
   1 => "Name of some Company", 
   2 =>"Name of some Company" 
   ....      
)
```

Into name of company are backspace also.
Explode - no good result.
Please,
help.

Regards

Comment: is it just text to begin with?  `preg_match_all('/(?P<index>[0-9]+)\|(?P<value>[^\n]+)\n/', $text, $matches ); assuming that each is on it's own line.

Comment: for explode you would have to break them on the line ending first or you get `Name of some Company\n2`