# Soap string convert into php array

Tags: php, arrays, soap

In regard into these question:

[Soap answert string - convert into arrray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737817/soap-answert-string-convert-into-arrray)

I have soap question:

```
$result = $soapclient->executeQuery($api_key, $database, $local, $qrf_file, $qif_file, $separator, $output_file, $params);
```

I have answers from soap like these:

```
Machine     |Number   |Words      |Something else   
Machine2    |Number2  |Words2     |Something else2 
Machine3    |Number3  |Words3     |Something else3
```

Rows are nothing separated.
 I need to convert soap answer into some php array. I tried:

```
$test2 = nl2br($result);
$test2 = explode("<br>", $test2);
```

or

```
 $result = explode("|", $result);
 $result2 = trim($result);
```

I need array like these :

```
Array {
    Machine1 => Array 
         (
           [mytext]  => Number
           [mytext2] => Words
           [mytext3] => 'Something else' 
          )
     Machine2 => Array 
         (
           [mytext]  => Number2
           [mytext2] => Words2
           [mytext3] => 'Something else2' 
          )
}
```

etc.

Please, Help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First we run `nl2br` as this will give us a common ending on each line regardless of what the actual new line character is. Then we can split the string on `<br />` into an array. This gives us an array with each line as its own element. From there, we go through each line, split it, trim every element of this new array, then add the needed row/format to a "final" array.

```
$result = nl2br($result);
$result = explode("<br />", $result);

$array = array();
foreach ($result as $var) {
    $var = explode("|", $var);
    $var = array_map("trim", $var);
    $array[$var[0]] = array("mytext" => $var[1], "mytext2" => $var[2], "mytext3" => $var[3]);
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the explode itself like this:

```
$str = "Machine     |Number   |Words      |Something else   
Machine2    |Number2  |Words2     |Something else2 
Machine3    |Number3  |Words3     |Something else3";

$first = explode("\n", $str);   //First explode using new line

$finalArr = [];
foreach ($first as $value) {
    $machines = explode("|", $value);   //Next explode using | operator
    $machines = array_map('trim', $machines);   //Trim the values to remove unwanted spaces
    $machineTitle = $machines[0];  
    $finalArr[$machineTitle] = [];
    unset($machines[0]);    //Unset the first index, we no need this anymore (used so that you can make it for any length of strings)
    foreach ($machines as $key => $value) {
        $finalArr[$machineTitle]["mytext".(($key-1)?:'')] = $value;  ///Just assign things
    }
}

print_r($finalArr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [Machine] => Array
        (
            [mytext] => Number
            [mytext1] => Words
            [mytext2] => Something else
        )

    [Machine2] => Array
        (
            [mytext] => Number2
            [mytext1] => Words2
            [mytext2] => Something else2
        )

    [Machine3] => Array
        (
            [mytext] => Number3
            [mytext1] => Words3
            [mytext2] => Something else3
        )

)
```